# Should I be using Ajax forms in MVC partial views for adding new data in real time?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views

I want to know if there is a better way to accomplish what I am doing or if my current approach is ok.  My current approach is giving me a little trouble so I need to see what I can do about it all.

In my MVC web application, I have dropdown lists which are searchable (handled by KendoUI Widgets) and I allow the user to add missing data to the database table which serves those dropdown lists.

**Example of Widget**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("Manufacturer")
.Filter("contains")
.OptionLabel("-- Select --")
.DataTextField("ManufacturerName")
.DataValueField("ManufacturerName")
.NoDataTemplate("No Data <a href=\"\\#\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"\\#modal_addManufacturer\">Add Manufacturer</a>")
 .DataSource(source => {
     source.Read(read => {
         read.Action("GetManufacturers", "Cars");
     }).ServerFiltering(false);
}))
```

The data is added via an ajax form in a partial view which is displayed using a bootstrap 4.0 modal trigger by a button in the no data template (see above example).

These dropdown lists appear in both `Create` and `Edit` views, in the `Create` view they work fine and as expected but within the `Edit` views, they have dictionary errors.

**Create View**

```
@model MyProject.Models.Cars

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Cars", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "NotifySuccess",
    OnFailure = "NotifyFailure"
},
new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    ...Form goes here with widgets etc

}
@Html.Partial("_Manufacturer")
```

**Popup form partial view**

```
@model MyProject.Models.Manufacturer
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_addManufacturer">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddManufacturer", "Cars", new AjaxOptions
                {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    OnSuccess = "Success",
                    OnFailure = "Fail"
                }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary()
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(l => l.ManufacturerName, new { @Class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.ManufacturerName, new { @Class = "form-control" })

                        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These errors seem to stem from the fact that the `Edit` method in the controller passes an `Id` parameter.  These leads me to the most obvious question, is this approach correct?  Should I be using ajax forms in modals to create data on the fly like this especially when the models they use are causing problems when the Id parameter is used on views such as edit.

Can anyone offer some guidance on what I can do about this?

Comment: The Id parameter is link with the value of the dropdownlist, can i assume? and also the dictionary that is coming with the error, is it becasue of the Id?

Comment: The Id and the dropdown are not related, nor should they be as the partial views ajax forms are supposed to act on their own adding data to a table.  The dictionary errors are because the expected type is of `Cars` but what is passed in is `Manufacturer`.  That's the problem with using these partial views and the reason I think it could be the wrong approach.